# List latest post out of 2 custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query

I have two post types Type_1 and Type_2

I'm trying to get the most recent out of both of them so if type_1 has a post created after the most recent of type_2 then I want to show that post and the other way around.

What is the best way of doing this?

I only want to show 1 post the most recent out of both

Answer (score 1):

Just set `post_type` to an array of types, and `posts_per_page` to `1` and you'll get the most recent post from those types.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'type_1', 'type_2' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$latest = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: See this is what I had thought as well but it doesn't seem to work it just gets the fist from the first post type even if i make a new post in the other

Comment: Make sure you don't have some code elsewhere in the theme or a plugin altering the query, like an incorrectly targeted `pre_get_posts` filter or something. If you `var_dump($latest)` after you run the query, you'll see the query vars and resultant SQL that was sent to the database. I've tested it here with latest WP and the 2016 theme and it works as expected.

Comment: @Milo Can't we use `wp_get_recent_posts()` to do that ?

Comment: @Ranuka - You could use that if you wanted to, it creates a new WP_Query object via get_posts, so arguments are the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that ended up working for me thanks for all your help

```
$type_1 = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'type_1',
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC'
));

   $type_1_query_obj = $type_1[0];
   $type_1_date = $type_1_query_obj->post_date;
   $type_1_name = $type_1_query_obj->post_title;



$type_2 = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'type_2',
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC'
));

   $type_2_query_obj = $type_2[0];
   $type_2_date = $type_2_query_obj->post_date;
   $type_2_name = $type_2_query_obj->post_title;


//compare the dates

if( strtotime($type_1_date) > strtotime($type_2_date) ) {
   echo $type_1_name;
}else{
   echo $type_2_name;
}
```